# Difficulty with installing gasp in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, gasp

I am having difficulty installing gasp in windows 7. Although I have the read instructions [here](http://dev.laptop.org/pub/gasp/downloads/) but they were not helpful. I am currently using python 2.7.

Comment: What difficulty exactly? Use `pip` or `easy_install` for installing python packages.

Comment: well first i installed pygame and then the package of gasp . pygame was succesfully installed and when i installed gasp  it  shows that could not create gasp . moreover when i run an graphical program in gasp windows ..while trying to close gasp output window  ...it do not close..

Answer (score 0):

AS per GASP latest version does not works on window ([source](http://dev.laptop.org/pub/gasp/downloads/)). on windows 0.2 version works you can find detail in attached source.